# Processing LoadLibrary failed with error 1114

Tags: dll, windows-10, processing

I am running Processing 3.2.4 on Windows 10, and am trying to run a simple 3D program:

```java
void setup(){
   size(1200, 800, P3D);
}

void draw(){  
}
```

Whenever I try running the program, instead of getting my program window, I am getting a popup with the following error:`LoadLibrary failed with error 1114: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed`.

What does this error mean, and how can I fix it? (I already tried reinstalling Processing).
I am running Processing 3.2.4 on Windows 10, and am trying to run a simple 3D program:

```java
void setup(){
   size(1200, 800, P3D);
}

void draw(){  
}
```

Whenever I try running the program, instead of getting my program window, I am getting a popup with the following error:`LoadLibrary failed with error 1114: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed`.

What does this error mean, and how can I fix it? (I already tried reinstalling Processing).

**Edit**: After clicking close on the error message, the console prints:

`Could not run the sketch (Target VM failed to initialize).
For more information, read revisions.txt and Help ? Troubleshooting.`

The default graphics renderer works. Restarting my computer or moving the installation to another folder hasn't worked either.

Comment: Does any more information show up in the console area? (Maybe a bunch of red text?) Have you tried the simple stuff like restarting your computer? Does the default renderer work? Have you tried moving the Processing installation to a different directory?

Comment: Just edited the question. I have tried my ProgramFiles folder, Desktop, and Downloads. Run as Administrator still gives the same error.

Comment: Turn on [loader snaps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2006/11/20/debugging-loadlibrary-failures/) to get details on the loading process.

Comment: It's going to be pretty hard to help you, since this problem is specific to your computer. But if I were you I might try using Processing as a library and seeing if the natives load if you run that way.

Comment: @KevinWorkman how do I do that?

Comment: @Shiven https://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/

Comment: @KevinWorkman I still get the same error.

Comment: @Shiven Okay, now it's a matter of figuring out which native fails to load. What happens if you don't load any of them? Then add them back one at a time until something breaks, and you'll know which one is the culprit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why this works, but go to Battery Power plans, and edit the `Switchable Dynamic Graphics ->  Global Setting` inside the advanced power plan settings and set both of the options to Maximize Performance.